# AWS Cluster Autoscaler is not removing the nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, autoscaling

I am playing around with the `autoscaler` in AWS and I find that my nodes are not being deleted even with the correct `scale-down-utilization-threshold` value.

Below are my configurations:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - ./cluster-autoscaler
        - --cloud-provider=aws
        - --namespace=kube-system
        - --node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled,k8s.io/cluster/mycluster123.us-west-2.dev
        - --expander=least-waste
        - --logtostderr=true
        - --scale-down-utilization-threshold=0.9
        - --scale-down-unneeded-time=1m
        - --scan-interval=10s
        - --skip-nodes-with-local-storage=false
```

Even after I adjusted the `scale-down-utilization-threshold` up to 0.9 (90%), the nodes are still being up and running and the logs are saying;

> I1207 12:24:03.529223
> scale down.go:785] No candidates for scale down
> I1207 12:24:10.382036
> reflector.go:384] k8s.10/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Watch close - *v1.Service total 0 items received
> I1207 12:24:13.542380
> static_autoscaler.go: 192] Starting main loop
> I1207 12:24:13.543224
> filter_out_schedulable.go:65] Filtering out schedulables
> I1207 12:24:13.543436
> filter_out_schedulable.go:130] 0 other pods marked as unschedulable can be scheduled.
> I1207 12:24:13.543592
> filter_out_schedulable.go: 130] 0 other pods marked as unschedulable can be scheduled
> I1207 12:24:13.543708
> filter_out_schedulable.go:90] No schedulable pods
> I1207 12:24:13.543814
> static_autoscaler.go:334] No unschedulable pods
> I1207 12:24:13.543918
> static_autoscaler.go:381] Calculating unneeded nodes
> I1207 12:24:13.544044
> 1 pre
> filtering processor.go:57] Skipping ip-10-2-11-5.us-west-2.compute. internal
> no node group config
> I1207 12:24:13.544154
> pre_filtering_processor.go:66] Skipping ip-10-2-13-221.us-west-2. compute. internal - node group min size reached
> I1207 12:24:13.544245
> pre_
> filtering processor.go:66] Skipping ip-10-2-19-220.us-west-2. compute. internal - node group min size reached
> I1207 12:24:13.544344
> nra
> filtering_processor.go:66] Skipping ip-10-2-28-179.us-west-2. compute. internal
> = node aroun min sire reached
> I1207 12:24:13.544433
> pre filtering processor.go:57] Skipping ip-10-2-27-105.us-west-2.compute. internal
> no node group config
> I1207 12:24:13.544741
> static autoscaler.go:440] Scale down status: unneededOnly=false lastScaleUpTime=2021-12-07 12:13:30.649716187 +0000 UTC m=+21.212580017 lastScaleDownDeleteTime=2021-12-07 12:13:30.649716287 +0
> 000 UTC m=+21.212580120 lastScaleDownFailTime=2021-12-07 12:13:30.649716378 +0000 UTC m=+21.212580208 scaleDownForbidden=false isDeleteInProgress=false scaleDownInCooldown=false
> I1207 12:24:13.544881
> static autoscaler.go: 453] Starting scale down
> I1207 12:24:13.545508
> 1 scale down. go: 785] No candidates for scale down

Current utilisation of the nodes are around 50%-60% which is below the `scale-down-utilization-threshold` value which is 90%

Can someone please help me why I am not being able to evict the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

From you log out put it tells you that the min size for the node groups have been reached.

`node group min size reached`

If the min size is set to 1, then the cluster can only scale down to the number of node groups you have.

From [their documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html) you should add the following options to the command

1. `--balance-similar-node-groups`
2. `--skip-nodes-with-system-pods=false`